# AutoCAD circle dimension annotation meanings

Tags: mechanical-engineering, autocad

What do the following annotations mean in this AutoCAD drawing mean?

```
R1.25 TYP (circle/hole Left)
2XØ1.0 (circle/hole Right)
Ø1.25 (circle/hole Bottom)
```

Based on those annotations, what is the diameter (or radius) of each of the three circles/holes in this AutoCAD drawing?

Also, if I'm reading correctly, the FILLET command can be used for "rounds" and "fillets", correct?  In reference to the dimension annotation R.5 (meaning radius 0.5).

[image]

Comment: Notes: Looks like the left and right hole radius is 0.5.  The outside circle from the holes seems to have a radius of 1.25 for the left and right.  The diameter annotation 2x appears to mean we have a quantity of two holes with a diameter of 1.0 (radius of 0.5).  The bottom hole is a mystery...

Comment: If you picked up on the 2x annotation, did you miss the very bottom entry of 1.25?

Comment: @fred_dot_u, does the 2X refer to the left and right holes having identical diameters, or the right and bottom holes having identical diameters?

Comment: Yes, the 2x refers to the top pair of holes, while the bottom has its own notation for 1.25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outside circle like you said has a radius of 1.25. The two holes at the top have a radius of 0.5 as you said and the bottom hole has a radius of 0.625.
What the drawing doesn't say I think is the "outside circle" of the bottom and right hole.

Comment: for the top right hole the outer radius would be 1.25 as a copy of the TYP marking on the other side, for the bottom hole it would be 0.625+0.75 = 1.375 if you want to preserve the typ thickness of the material, or 1.25 as a copy of the typ radius. If the drawing is to scale then it looks like the latter.

Comment: What bothers me is the lines from the right hole to the bottom hole are all parallel, yet the holes have different radii.  So, I have no idea if I need to move the circle or NOT make them parallel lines.   I think the R1.25 TYP might mean that all three outside circles (of the three holes are R1.25, and then I can just deal with the parallel line ambiguity between the right hole and bottom hole.

Comment: I think the offset between the bottom circle and bottom outside circle is different than the other two holes, and then the lines can remain parallel